# How to enable Facebook apps for secure URL[https] users using same folder in server

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-canvas

I have created a facebook application which can server both http and https users. As of now, I'm using two different folders on the server on each for https and https respectively.
e.g.

```
http://example.com/folder 
and 
https://example.com/folder_secure
```

I personally feel that this may be unnecessary redundancy[though clueless of the workaround], is there anyway I can include code for both http and https in a single folder and set the canvas url and secure canvas url as something like

```
http://example.com/folder
and 
https://example.com/folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-thinking this.  HTTP and HTTPS are just access mechanisms, they don't necessarily *go* to different places.  Configure your web server to use the same directories for both protocols and you'll be fine.

**EDIT**

The way a URL like `https://example.com/folder_secure` is translated into a file-path on the server like `/var/www/html/folder` is controlled by the configuration of the web server.  You're going to have to read the manual for whatever server you're using.  If it is Apache, the variable you need is DocumentRoot.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this, help me get over my ignorance in this stuff... What about the resources within some file of the app. How can I make it to be fetched from https when needed? Thanks for the reply man..

Comment: If you make the links to resources relative, you wont have the protocol prefix and thus they'll be called using http or https appropriately. Like Malvolio said, I think sounds like you're over thinking it. Good luck though.

Comment: @stupid-phil -- you should promote that to an actual answer.  It's a good idea.

Comment: @Malvolio, Let me ask what should I do with the links in places like, where i can't make it relative. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` and 
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: @saji89 - my answer (unlike Phil's) does not have anything to do with relative/non-relative URLs.  Fix your config.